How many pounds of thrust can a TBM 900 pull at full thrust?
Curious of how many lbs/thrust can a single engine like the Socata TBM 900 (or a similar airplane) pull at sea level while parked at full thrust?

The Daher Socata TBM has a climb rate of 2200 fpm at 124 knots and a glide ratio 1 to 10.  This all works out to a thrust to weight ratio of 0.275

What propeller? Without one thrust is limited to what is produced by the exhaust of the engine.

In the Pilots Operating Handbook there are 2 clues to thrust output:  glide ratio and climb performance.
Glide ratio gives thrust requirement for level flight at Vbg.
For a Cessna 172 this is about 1 to 9.  For a weight of 2400 pounds this is around 270 pounds of thrust.
Climb performance at Vy, which is fairly close to Vbg, is around 730 feet per minute.  At a forward speed of 70 knots we have 730/(70×6076/60)×2400 = 247 lbs climbing thrust.
Add the two together and divide by 160 horsepower equals 3.23 pounds per horsepower.
That would be for a fixed pitch, and thrust output is a function of engine power × prop efficiency factor, which will vary with airspeed.
The 900 TBM has a glide ratio of 1 to 10 at 7000 pounds:
700 pounds thrust for level flight.
It climbs at 2200 feet per minute with a climb thrust of: 2200/(124×6076/60)×7000 = 1226 pounds
(700+1226)/850 = 2.26 pounds per horsepower.
The prop is 91 inches vs 75 inches for the 172.  It has 5 blades spinning at 2000 rpm vs 2 blades for the 172 (at a slightly higher rpm).
Though the lower thrust per horsepower efficiency may be surprising (should it be?), the fuel economy cross-over to jets is less.

You can ballpark it. A decently efficient constant speed propeller makes around 5lbs per horsepower, give or take. The PT6-66 in the 900 is 850 HP, so you could say somewhere around 4000-5000 lbs is a  reasonable guesstimate.

The thrust estimate may be a bit high.  The plane itself is only about 7400 lb at max TOW, and the take-off acceleration initiated at nearly 0.7g from thrust of this propeller would be remarkable.

I was going to say the same but since I'm not an expert in the area can't speak too much ....  I find it high even though it is indeed a high performance airplane....

A more conservative number would be about 4.5 lb/hp. 3800 lbs.

@Gabe there is a video online where a guy with a Cessna 140 takes an actual thrust measurement. 85hp Cont, fixed pitch prop. He measured 300lbs, or 3.6 lbs/hp. Prob is with a fixed pitch the engine isn't making 85 hp static, maybe 75, until it gets moving and it can wind up to redline RPM, and the prop's efficiency is poor when static. A CS prop will be at redline while static and is running at much higher efficiency with its blades optimized for the torque. 4.5 to 5.5 lbs/hp is not unreasonable.

I would definitely agree power would be greater at higher altitude on a thrust to TAS basis.
